# Unable to pass values to a function on click of a button

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript and was just trying to implement a simple form. However, I am unable to submit it since the values that are entered in the textbox are not getting passed further to the function that I call on clicking the submit button.

I have seen similar questions and even followed the answers still for some reason I only get undefined instead of the data passed.

Below is the code:

Html:

```
<form >
    First Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtfirstName" 
    />

    Second Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtsecondName" 
    />

    User Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtuserName"
    />

    Email:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtemail"
    />

    Password:
    <input 
        type="password" 
        id="txtpassword" 
    />

    <input 
        type="button" 
        id= "btnsubmit" 
        value="SUBMIT" 
        onclick="submit("name","surname","user","mail","word")" 
    />
</form>

<script>
var fname = "";
var sname = "";
var uname = "";
var email = "";
var password = "";
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");

submitButton.onclick = function submit(fname,sname,uname,email,password) {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"); 

    if(confirm) {
        alert("Below is the data entered by you:" + "\n" + fname + "\n" + sname + "\n" + uname + "\n" 
         + email + "\n" + password ) 
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: where are you assigning a value to the variables? You are just setting them to empty value in your code. Where are you assigning them the value from the form?

Comment: onclick="submit("name","surname","user","mail","word")" I thought I could do that here... but that was wrong I guess..

Comment: what is name? where is it defined?

Comment: name is the value... I wasn't able to get the values dynamically and so I was trying to check once with hard coded values... so fname was suppose to have the value name...

Answer (score 2):

The function called at the onclick attribute for the input does not exist and it will never work.

What you did was almost correct. You added the click event for the submit button that calls a function. That function will always (i think so) have one parameter (Event type) and not those added by you.

In order to retrieve the values for the inputs, you need to retrieve them in that function.

Check the snippet below.

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");

submitButton.onclick = function submit() {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"); 

    if(confirm) {
        var fname = document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value;
        var sname = document.getElementById('txtsecondName').value;
        var uname = document.getElementById('txtuserName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;
        alert("Below is the data entered by you:" + "\n" + fname + "\n" + sname + "\n" + uname + "\n" 
         + email + "\n" + password ) 
    } 
}
```

```html
<form >
    First Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtfirstName" 
    />

    Second Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtsecondName" 
    />

    User Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtuserName"
    />

    Email:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtemail"
    />

    Password:
    <input 
        type="password" 
        id="txtpassword" 
    />

    <input 
        type="button" 
        id= "btnsubmit" 
        value="SUBMIT" 
    />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks !.. did var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit"); make the difference?

Comment: or does this: var fname = document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value;
        var sname = document.getElementById('txtsecondName').value;
        var uname = document.getElementById('txtuserName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;  make it work?

Comment: Yes, to the second one. The fact that you retrieve the input values after confirming the popup.

Comment: what if I have hardcoded the values? I mean I know that's not the way things are generally done but just incase... if I want pass values while calling the function like onclick="submit("name","surname","user","mail","word")" then ?

Answer (score 1):

Here I fixed that:

```html
<form >
    First Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtfirstName" 
    />

    Second Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtsecondName" 
    />

    User Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtuserName"
    />

    Email:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtemail"
    />

    Password:
    <input 
        type="password" 
        id="txtpassword" 
    />

    <input 
        type="button" 
        id= "btnsubmit" 
        value="SUBMIT" 
    />
</form>

<script>
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");

submitButton.onclick = function () {
    var fname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
    var sname = document.getElementById("txtsecondname").value;
    var uname = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"); 

    if(confirm) {
        alert("Below is the data entered by you:" + "\n" + fname + "\n" + sname + "\n" + uname + "\n" 
         + email + "\n" + password ) 
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: um...this doesn't work ...I get "below is the data entered by you: [Object MouseEvent] undefined undefined undefined undefined".. :-(

Comment: yes this works! thanks :-) now I know what makes the difference...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle working:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lk9t0bxj/

```
<form>
    First Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtfirstName" 
    />

    Second Name:1
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtsecondName" 
    />

    User Name:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtuserName"
    />

    Email:
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="txtemail"
    />

    Password:
    <input 
        type="password" 
        id="txtpassword" 
    />

    <input 
        type="button" 
        id= "btnsubmit" 
        value="SUBMIT" 
        onclick="submit()" 
    />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var fname = "";
var sname = "";
var uname = "";
var email = "";
var password = "";
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");

submitButton.onclick = function submit() {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"); 

    if(confirm) {
            fname = document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value;
            sname = document.getElementById('txtsecondName').value;
            uname = document.getElementById('txtuserName').value;
            email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;
            password = document.getElementById('txtpassword').value;

        alert("Below is the data entered by you:" + "\n" + fname + "\n" + sname + "\n" + uname + "\n" 
         + email + "\n" + password ) 
    } 
}
```

There were some errors:
Confusion with quotation marks:

```
onclick="submit("name","surname","user","mail","word")"
```

There is no need to pass the name fields:

```
onclick="submit()"
```

You should get the field values and put it in the variables defined:

```
fname = document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by adding `onsubmit` callback to your `<form>` element, and changing your `<input>` type to `submit`. You don't have to add in individual ids for all of your input, instead you can use `event.target[INPUT_NAME]` to get your input element, and get the value of that element with `INPUT.value`.

Working sample code :

```js
const handleOnSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { fname, sname, uname, email, password } = event.target;
  confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
  if (confirm) {
   alert(
    "Below is the data entered by you:" +
     "\n" +
     fname.value +
     "\n" +
     sname.value +
     "\n" +
     uname.value +
     "\n" +
     email.value +
     "\n" +
     password.value
   );
  }
 };
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handleOnSubmit(event)">
 First Name:
 <input type="text" name="fname" />

 Second Name:
 <input type="text" name="sname" />

 User Name:
 <input type="text" name="uname" />

 Email:
 <input type="text" name="email" />

 Password:
 <input type="password" name="password" />

 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this is use `add.event.listener` and `template literals`.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");


submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var fname = document.getElementById("txtfirstName").value;
  var sname = document.getElementById("txtsecondName").value;
  var uname = document.getElementById("txtuserName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;

  confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"); 

  if(confirm) {
      alert(`Below is the data entered by you: \n ${fname} \n ${sname} \n ${uname} \n ${email} \n ${password}`) 
  } 

})
```